# Angular http request is delayed. How can I speed it up?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

When I call HTTP request to api server, the response is delayed.

After displayed empty table, the response is displayed after 2 seconds.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `HTTP` request are `async` in nature

Comment: yeah, so I'm using angular 2 promise like this:  
  'code' return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
   this.http.get('/users' , {headers: headers})
       .map(res => res.json())
       .subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res);
       }, (err) => {
         reject(err);
       });
  });

Comment: I don't get what delay means? Is delay means that your http request takes time to complete or You have already response and It takes time to display?

Comment: We can't do anything with the delay. But we can make it to wait the table component rendering, untill the API response by using `resolvers`

Comment: how to do that?  
please share more details.

Comment: you need to measure the server response time may be there is issue on the server, or could be `network/connection` issue in case if you are calling some remote service.

Comment: Just show preloader :) this is internet man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `resolvers` may fix, displaying empty table. Here is an example, of how to use `resolver`

```
// resolver.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';

@Injectable()
export class ContactResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.contactsService.getContact(route.params['id']);
  }
}
```

.

```
// router.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactsListComponent } from './contacts-list.component';
import { ContactsDetailComponent } from './contacts-detail.component';
import { ContactResolve } from './contact.resolve';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ContactsListComponent },
  { 
    path: 'contact/:id',
    component: ContactsDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      contact: ContactResolve
    }
  }
];
```

[An example with plunker, of how to use resolvers in angular2](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: Please provide an example in your answer. Links come and go.

Comment: I think resolvers is pretty good, but if you have several loading parts in one page, some of them is loading faster, some - not, and I want to see page before loading parts is done. But i have to wait until resolver resolves data.

Comment: If a page has several loading parts, then we may have to use `structural directives` like `*ngIf` , to hide the particular part untill getting its `response`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are taking data from the server, network flight is supposed to consume some time depending on the speed of your internet connection and how good your backend servers response to your query. Now there some options through which you can make user experience better in your case.

- You can show a loading icon till the time servers don't respond. This can be achieved using ngIf.
- You can use resolver as pointed out by @Rajez.
- You can use `async` pipe on your table so that angular knows that it need to subscribe on data and wait instead of displaying the empty table.

Hope this helps! If you need code snippet for any of the approaches do mention in comment.